# Android Studio localhost ports - Google Sign In during development

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I have a question... I'm developing an app in Flutter that uses Google Sign In. In the iOS and Android emulator is not painful, but for the web I have some problems and doubts.

I already put the URL and localhost ports on the Google Console. My question is... is possible to configure in Android Studio always the same port to run flutter web on Chrome?

Thank you very much!